# Does quantum mechanics depend solely on electromagnetic waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem

I am beginning to learn quantum mechanics. Since determining the position of an object involves probing by electromagnetic waves and since i have read a simple derivation of [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) which says that uncertainty in momentum of a quantum particle is proportional to the momentum of light (or e.m.) used, I am beginning to wonder whether the theory of quantum mechanics is solely based on measurement using electromagnetic waves? In that case it is not a fundamental law. If we measure the position of a particle using its gravitational field change, does then the uncertainty exist?
Pardon me if my question sounds silly.

Comment: Short answer: the uncertainty is always there. The EM thing is extended to all measurement methods due to wave particle duality.